# Composite Function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I badly need help with a question.

Just to start of by defining the functions.

$f: \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = 0.2\cos(\pi x)-7$.

$g: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ where $g(x) = \frac{5x}2$

$h(x) = f(g(x))$ therefore $h(x)= 0.2\cos(\frac{5x\pi}2)-7$

a) What is the range of $h$?

b) What is the domain and codomain of $h$?

c) Is $h$ surjective (onto)?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem? Even if it hasn't been successful, it's good to post what you've tried so that we can help you better.

Comment: a) I would start by as easy as possible say that the domain is what x can be, therefore x is ℕ. [-∞, ∞]. The codomain is what h can take based on anything on x. Therefore between -36/5 and 36/5.
b) The range is what the function can take from the domain. The cosine function has the range of [-1,1], so 0.2[−1,1]=[−0.2,0.2] so that [−0.2,0.2]−7=[−7.2,−6.8]. 
c) I'm lost on how to find out if it's an onto function though.. They have stated that I should do a proof to be able to know if its a onto function or not..

Comment: Everything you said in the last comment should added (by way of editing) into your original question -- that will make your question a whole lot better!

Answer (score 1):

Can you write out a closed function for $h?$

Some other things to think about.  $-1\le \cos x \le 1$

$\cos x$ achieves its min \ max at $x = \pi$ and $x = 0$ (more generally at $x = (2n+1)\pi$ and $2n \pi$

With the constraints that $x\in \mathbb N$ is it possible for $h$ to achieve this min and this max?  For what values of $x?$

If the $\cos g(x)\pi$ factor equals $1$ what does that imply the max of $h(x)$ is?
and if $\cos g(x)\pi = -1?$

The domain of $h$ will equal the domain of $g$ unless there are values of $x$ such that $h$ will be undefined?  Do any such values exist?

If the range of x is something less than all real numbers can $h$ be surjective?

More generally do surjective functions from $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ exist?

Comment: +1 especially for the last paragraph!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said in your own comment to the question, you seem to be quite confused regarding the concepts of the *range* and the *codomain* of a function. But good news: your answer that the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ is perfectly correct!

The **domain** and **codomain** of a function $f:X\to Y$ are simply the sets $X$ and $Y$, respectively. So when they are given to you, you don't even need to do anything to find them! You just need to understand this definition of what they are. One more definition that you need to understand is that of a composite function: if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$, then by definition their composition is the function $g\circ f:X\to Z$, defined via $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$ for all $x\in X$. So simply be definition, the domain and the codomain of this function are …

Now, the **range** is a different story. For a function $f:X\to Y$, its range is the set of all actually attained output values:
$$\operatorname{range}(f) = \{y\in Y \mid \text{ there exists }x\in X \text{ such that } f(x)=y\}.$$
It's a subset (part) of the codomain $Y$, but it may or may not be all of $Y$. In fact, by definition a function is called **surjective** if its range is the entire codomain.

To find the range in this example, start by trying $x=1,2,3,4$, i.e. plug them in. And then notice what happens when you plug in even or odd values of $x$, and maybe reason a little further from there. (Hint: there are only three possible output values here.)